# How does Python's triple-quote string work?

Tags: python, string

How should this function be changed to return `"123456"`?

```
def f():
    s = """123
    456"""
    return s
```

UPDATE: Everyone, the question is about understanding how to not have \t or whatever when having a multiline comment, not how to use the `re` module.

Comment: Is this homework?  
Hint: Your string is "123<some whitespace>456"

Comment: This is not homework. I'm trying to understand how `"""` works.

Comment: But how do I not have the \t in it?

Comment: @cool-RR: and how are we supposed to know that you have `\t` in it?

Comment: @cool-RR: By not adding the tab in the beginning of the row.

When asking questions, you really need to explain what the problem is, not the question that is on top of your head.

Comment: @SilentGhost: I guess a person who understands how Python works with `"""` will see immediately that my string would contain a `\t` (or spaces, which are equivalent for this matter)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Don't use a triple-quoted string when you don't want extra whitespace, tabs and newlines.

Use implicit continuation, it's more elegant:

```
def f():
    s = ('123'
         '456')
    return s
```

Comment: This used to come naturally to me but not when I had to plug in variable values using a ex:%s , but alas, even the following works:
`s = ('String %s '`
`'String %s') %('foo', 'bar')`

Answer (score 19):

```
def f():
  s = """123\
456"""
  return s
```

Don't indent any of the blockquote lines after the first line; end every line except the last with a backslash.

Comment: +1: even though I do not like bashslashes: could use replace('\n','')

Comment: ... and not {{{return s.replace('\n', '')}}}, but rather in the assignment itself: {{{456""".replace('\n', '')}}}

Answer (score 16):

Subsequent strings are concatenated, so you can use:

```
def f():
    s = ("123"
         "456")
    return s
```

This will allow you to keep indention as you like.

Comment: Note to OP - no comma between "123" and "456".  The ()'s are there to avoid having to use '\' for line continuations.

Answer (score 12):

```
textwrap.dedent("""\
                123
                456""")
```

From the standard library. First "\" is necessary because this function works by removing the common leading whitespace.

Comment: Does not answer the question, but does answer Google query! Actually asked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412374/python-triple-quote-multi-line-indentation

Answer (score 7):

Maybe I'm missing something obvious but what about this:

```
def f():
    s = """123456"""
    return s
```

or simply this:

```
def f():
    s = "123456"
    return s
```

or even simpler:

```
def f():
    return "123456"
```

If that doesn't answer your question, then please clarify what the question is about.

Comment: About understanding how to not have \t or whatever when have a multiline comment.

Comment: A triple quoted string isn't a multiline comment, it's a raw string, and contains exactly what you type into it.

Comment: Technically a triple-quoted string is not a raw string, as backslash escapes are still interpreted. It is a normal python string in which unescaped newlines are retained (instead of causing a parse error). You can make a truly raw triple-quoted string with r"""blabla""". This is useful for making regex patterns which need to contain both single and double quotes and backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check this [str.splitlines([keepends])](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines)

> Return a list of the lines in the string, breaking at line boundaries.
> This method uses the universal newlines approach to splitting lines.
> Line breaks are not included in the resulting list unless keepends is
> given and true.
>
> Python recognizes "\r", "\n", and "\r\n" as line boundaries for 8-bit strings.

So, for the problem at hand ... we could do somehting like this..

```
>>> s = """123
... 456"""
>>> s
'123\n456'
>>> ''.join(s.splitlines())
'123456'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
re.sub('\D+', '', s)
```

will return a string, if you want an integer, convert this string with `int`.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
import re
```

and then

```
    return re.sub("\s+", "", s)
```

Answer (score -3):

My guess is:

```
def f():
    s = """123
    456"""
    return u'123456'
```

Minimum change and does what is asked for.

Comment: Was probably downvoted because the function was supposed to return a string.

Comment: You're right, it probably has to return a string and I returned an integer, anyway I don't get the downvoted thing either, I'm new to python

Comment: so change the last line to return "123456"

Comment: Now that I re-read the question I know why my answer was downvoted, the question is referring to 'How does Python’s triple-quote string work?' an my answer doesn't comment anything about it