# Why does python [printf r """] return the string "..." and can't exit

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why does `print r"""` return the string `...` and doesn't exit?

When I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the console displays a new row preceded by the string `...`

[image: the display of console]

Answer (score 7):

Because the three quotes are seen as the beginning of a triple-quoted string. It is waiting for you to type another set of triple quotes.

```
>>> print r"""
... blah
... """

blah

>>>
```

For more information see:

- [How does Python's triple-quote string work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1520548/7432)
- https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/introduction.html#strings; search for `"""`

(The second link is to 2.7 docs since your example used python 2.x syntax).

A direct quote from the python documentation:

> String literals can span multiple lines. One way is using triple-quotes: """...""" or '''...'''. End of lines are automatically included in the string, but it’s possible to prevent this by adding a \ at the end of the line.

Comment: [But what are triple quotes?](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) _String literals can span multiple lines. One way is using triple-quotes: `"""..."""` or `'''...'''`. End of lines are automatically included in the string, but it’s possible to prevent this by adding a \ at the end of the line._

Answer (score 0):

`print r"""` starts a multi-line string.

Because the string hasn't been terminated with another `"""` the interpreter keeps printing `...`, waiting for you to type the next line  or match the opening quotes with a closing one. So, if you type `"""` again the standard interpreter prompt `>>>` will reappear or resume.

[Python 3 implementation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings):

```
>>> print("""
...   
... abc
... 
... ggg
... 
... """)


abc

ggg


>>>
```

[Python 2.7 implementation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/introduction.html#strings):

```
>>> print r"""
... blah
... black sheep
... """

black sheep
blah
```